# XML: Deserialize Disconnected Single Elements Inside of Array

Tags: c#, xml

I've got some XML I'm working with that returns an array of objects, but at the very top of the array there is a couple of disconnected objects that contain information if the request was valid, how many results there is, etc. My problem is that I can't figure out how to deserialize those objects into the properties I need. Here's the XML and the code I've got so far:

**XML**

```
<ItemSearchResponse>
    <Items>
        <Request>
            <IsValid>True</IsValid>
        </Request>
        <TotalResults>90</TotalResults>
        <TotalPages>9</TotalPages>
        <Item />
        ...
    </Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

**C#**

```
public class Response {
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in my code, I'm trying to pull individual objects out and apply them as properties to my `Response` object because I think it makes more sense if they sit there. So, how do I take the `ItemSearchResponse.Items.Request.IsValid` and turn it into `Response.IsValid`? Same question for the `TotalResults` and `TotalPages` properties?

Comment: Aside from writing a lot of custom deserialization code (such as implementing `IXmlSerializable` in your class), have you considered defining your properties to traverse the data (i.e., `public bool IsValid { get { return Items.Request.IsValid; } }`)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding a `Request` object as a property, but it wasn't being deserialized and kept coming back as null. Maybe I was screwing it up, Idk...